# SAS - results of %let and libname combinations

Tags: path, sas

I'm currently learning SAS and I got a code to be adapted and reused but first I have to understand it. My question is about just a small part of it (top of the code). Here it is:

```
%let dir=/home/user/PROJECT/CODES/;
%let dir_project=/home/user/PROJECT/;

libname inp "&dir_project" compress=yes;
libname out "&dir.out" compress=yes;

%let tg=out.vip;
```

My questions are:

1. What does &dir.out mean? What is it referring to? I suppose it's something called "out". Is it looking for a database OUT? If yes and all my databases are usually temporary ones in WORK should I change it to WORK.OUT?
2. What is the resulting path of "tg"? I doubt that it is: "/home/user/PROJECT/CODES/out.vip".

Originally the code was referring to some locations on C: drive but I work entirely in SAS Studio so I have to adapt it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two statements define two macro variables, `DIR` and `DIR_PROJECT`. In the second two statements you use those macro variables to define two librefs, `INP` and `OUT`.  The last statement just defines another macro variable named `TG`.

Macro variable references start with `&` and are followed by the name of the macro variable to expand.  SAS will stop looking for the macro variable name when is sees a character that cannot be part of a macro variable name or a period.  That is why the first libname statement uses the value of the `DIR_PROJECT` macro variable instead of the `DIR` macro variable. The period in the second libname statement tells SAS that you want to replace `&dir.` with the value of the macro variable `DIR`. If you had instead just written `&dirout` then SAS would look for a macro variable named `DIROUT`.

Macro variable just contain text.  The meaning of the text depends on what SAS code you generate with them.  So the first two macro variable look like they contain absolute paths to directories on your Unix file system, since they start from the root node `/` and end with a `/`. This is confirmed by how you use them to generate libname statements.

By adding the constant text `out` after the path in the second libname statement the result is that you are looking for a sub-directory named `out` in the directory that the value of the macro variable `DIR` names.

As for the last macro variable `TG` what it means depends on how it is used. Since it is of the form of two names separated by a period then it looks like it can be used to refer to a SAS dataset. Especially since the first name is the same as one of the librefs that you defined in the libname statements.  So you might use that macro variable in code like this:

```
proc print data=&tg ; run;
```

Which would be expanded into:

```
proc print data=out.vip ; run;
```

In that case you are looking for the SAS dataset named VIP in the library named OUT.  So you would be looking for the Unix file named:

```
/home/user/PROJECT/CODES/out/vip.sas7bdat
```

Now if you used that macro variable in some SQL code like this:

```
select &tg ...
```

Then it would expand to

```
select out.vip ....
```

and in that case you would be referencing a variable named VIP in an input dataset named (or aliased as) OUT.

Answer (score 1):

1 - `&dir.` is a macro variable.  The period marks the end of the variable, and thus `&dir.out` resolves to `/home/user/PROJECT/CODES/out` at runtime.  Your libname statement will now link the libref `out` to this physical location.

2 - the `tg` variable is a dataset reference, in the form "library.dataset".  Here, `out` is the library, and `vip` is the dataset.  This way you can write code such as:

```
data &tg.;
  set sashelp.class; 
run;
```

To create the dataset `vip` in the `out` library.

In this way, you are in fact (almost) right.  The resulting path of `&tg.` (which resolves to `out.vip`) will be `/home/user/PROJECT/CODES/out/vip.sas7bdat`.

Comment: OK. So if I understand correctly the "&dir.out" resolves to the actual folder names "out" and "tg=out.vip" to a variable named "vip" in database named "out"?

Comment: `&dir` resolves to `/home/user/PROJECT/CODES/` and `&tg` resolves to `out.vip`.  All datasets can be one or two level..  eg `work.blah` or `blah`.  The first part is the library (analagous to a database or schema).  The second part is the dataset (analagous to a table).  I highly suggest doing a basic SAS course :-)  The SAS certification prep guide is excellent.

Comment: Great. Now the code works. I was a bit confused with the usage of the same name for a folder and a database :) I'm doing now one online basic SAS course, but it's very basic.Thanks!

Comment: The path for the dataset referenced by the value of the macro variable `TG` is `/home/user/PROJECT/CODES/out/vip.sas7bat`.  You left out the member name.